# With automated hyperparameter tuning available, do we still need to learn hyperparameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, hyperparameter-tuning

Tools like AWS Sagemaker have capability to do automated hyperparameter tuning, even with complex algos like Neural Networks using Tensorflow. So do we still need to learn how to do hyperparameter tuning, or simply leave it to tools like Sagemaker? Thx

Answer (score 1):

> So do we still need to learn how to do hyperparameter tuning

If you're saying this based on the context of acquiring a new skill, then go for it. It's always a good thing to get an idea an idea of how hyper-parameter testing is done for real. In addition to sagemaker you can use tools like [weights and biases](https://www.wandb.com/)